# After I remove the apk, whenever I start Debug it tells me the package is not installed

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have my Emulator open, and using Command Prompt I remove my application. I didn't closed the Emulator.

Then I go to Eclipse and hit Debug, but doesn't deploy the apk to the emulator, just tells me the package not yet registered with the system.

`New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.`

Restarting the emulator is not an option, as that takes 10-15 minutes.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have encountered this occasionally. Doing a clean project before rebuilding and redeploying seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, you saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 2):

This is eclipse (the point is eclipse can not run your app because can not start the right intent because can not find the right package) and one of the workaround of this is to rename your package in the manifest for example rename

```
package="com.hernblog.GreenThumbs"
```

to

```
package="com.hernblog.GreenThumbs1"
```

compile and build this, then put it back to the name you wanted

```
package="com.hernblog.GreenThumbs"
```

works as a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Clean and re-build may not help. 
So, in that case remove the app from your device.
Then re-run your project on your device. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different solutions for this problem, I found that the line

```
<application android:debuggable="true" />
```

in my AndroidManifest was causing this problem.

Removing this line fixed it for me.

**Note:** You can still build with debugging mode without this line by using the ndk-build option NDK_DEBUG=1

Answer (score 0):

im also having same problem.

I just commit my src,res folder in svn.

Then i check out new project from svn then it will works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your "Enabled" option in manifest! Mine turned to off, somehow ..

Answer (score -1):

I have also had this problem.

For me it was the fact that my launcher activity (the one with the Launch intent) did not have the "android:label" attribute
***WRONG!!!***

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.LogListActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

***RIGHT*** - Note the SplashScreenActivity

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.LogListActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You answered this on another forum as well, and I will supply the same response: NO, this is NOT the case. Activities do NOT require the label attribute.