# Android package not registered on nexus 7 but working on S3

Tags: android, platform

I got a problem running an app from ADT (eclipse) on a Asus Nexus 7. On an SGS 3 however no problem occurs. ADT outputs the following error:

```
[ - com.myorg.project.package] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[ - com.myorg.project.package] Starting activity com.myorg.project.package.MyActivity on device XYZ
[ - com.myorg.project.package] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.myorg.project.package/.MyActivity }
[ - com.myorg.project.package] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[ - com.myorg.project.package] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {om.myorg.project.package/com.myorg.project.package.MyActivity} does not exist.
```

I found the following similar questions:

- [Android error activity manager type 3 (Eclipse, using jni)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753102/android-error-activity-manager-type-3-eclipse-using-jni)
- [New package not yet registered with the system. Error on a real phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996702/new-package-not-yet-registered-with-the-system-error-on-a-real-phone)

and did everything suggested: Removing any old version, rebooting the device, cleaning the project, restarting IDE. But nothing worked for me.
Since it works on the SGS 3 I can't imagine any bug in the code, but suspect the configuration or the Android Version to be the problem. I can however launch an example app on the Nexus 7 via the IDE.

The Nexus 7 runs Android 4.3.
The SGS 3 runs Android 4.1.2.
Both updated stock versions.

Any ideas on how to eliminate possible causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had

```
<application
    android:enabled="false"/>
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml. That blocked the execution on the Nexus 7 with Android 4.3 but not on the SGS3 with Android 4.1.2. I don't understand why this attribute is ignored on the SGS3 and could find if it was added in 4.3 (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#enabled). I hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Why do you even have that in your manifest at the application element?

Comment: @RvdK was from an example I think, copy&paste is bad ;), any idea on why this has no effect on the S3 running Android 4.1.2?